# Need password each time start hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I installed the Hadoop 2.6.4 on the Ubuntu server, and i use SSH to login the Ubuntu server from my Mac, since the rsa key was used for login, so i don't have to input any password. but when i run the start_dfs.sh to start the server, i do have to input the password for each service as below:

```
jianrui@cloudfoundry:~$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Password: 
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/jianrui/hadoop-2.6.4/logs/hadoop-dingjianrui-namenode-cloudfoundry.out
Password: 
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/jianrui/hadoop-2.6.4/logs/hadoop-dingjianrui-datanode-cloudfoundry.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
Password: 
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/jianrui/hadoop-2.6.4/logs/hadoop-dingjianrui-secondarynamenode-cloudfoundry.out
dingjianrui@cloudfoundry:~$
```

Comment: I have already found the problem, the command "ssh localhost" doesn't work properly, it always ask me to input a password, if i use the ssh-keygen to generate the rsa key pair, and import the public key to the authorizied_keys file, then "ssh localhost" doesn't need a password anymore, then start_dfs.sh also doesn't need a password. the tricky part is the ssh localhost use the rsa key by default, event the dsa key is generated, it doesn't use it by default, i don't know where i can change the default key used by the ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue using below commands.

The following commands are used for generating a key value pair using SSH. Copy the public keys form id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys, and provide the owner with read and write permissions to authorized_keys file respectively.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa 
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all of this you don't succeed.

Try below.

$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""

$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa [id]@[domain]

I'm using Redhat7

If you may use IP address instead of a domain name.
and
You wanna use a domain name easily.
Edit your /etc/hosts file.
ex>  192.168.0.11 cluster01

The matter is just how to copy a  key file to another machine.
I succeed so easily.